# CSS browser inconsistency: Margins on abs element inside a centered flexbox

Tags: css, browser, flexbox, margin, absolute

I'm seeing a browser inconsistency when calculating "flex center" on an absolute positioned element with margins. Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/JasonHorsleyTech/pen/MMwKjx), and here's the HTML

```
<style>
div {
  height:100px;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}   
p {
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  margin-top:50px;
  font-size:50px;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>This is some text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

When viewed in Chrome and Edge, the text element is at the bottom of the div. But when viewed in Opera and Firefox, the text element is below the border.

It seems like some browsers are flex centering JUST the element while others are flex centering the element AND it's margins.

My question is... Which browser is handling this the "correct" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in the spec : [Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

> As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout.

Comment: Then why are both browsers horizontally centering? It's |----abs elem----|. If abs children shouldn't participate in the flex, shouldn't the element be at the left of the parent? I.E. where it would be if justify-content and align-items wasn't there? Eh, I mean I guess this is hacky anyway... Thanks for the w3 reference!